Task send_verify_email[dea32c62-98b6-4418-93af-5c5d0f0f20ad] raised unexpected: TimeoutError(110, 'Connection timed out')
After I enable celery in the terminal, I click Send email again and wait for a moment to get the result.My configuration file is also configured, and I will receive front-end requests, and the back-end server is normal, but there is still a timeout problem, I do not know why.
[2024-05-13 23:09:54,387: INFO/MainProcess] Task send_verify_email[dea32c62-98b6-4418-93af-5c5d0f0f20ad] received
[2024-05-13 23:12:05,560: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task send_verify_email[dea32c62-98b6-4418-93af-5c5d0f0f20ad] raised unexpected: TimeoutError(110, 'Connection timed out')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin/.virtualenvs/haoke_mall/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 453, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/.virtualenvs/haoke_mall/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 736, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/admin/haoke18/hk18/celery_tasks/email/tasks.py", line 27, in send_verify_email
    send_mail(subject, "", EMAIL_FROM, [to_email], html_message=html_message)
  File "/home/admin/.virtualenvs/haoke_mall/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/home/admin/.virtualenvs/haoke_mall/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/admin/.virtualenvs/haoke_mall/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/admin/.virtualenvs/haoke_mall/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 62, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 845, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 833, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

I configured Django with the correct email address, but the connection still failed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Looks like an issue with your SMTP Django settings.
